# Caching the result of a function call in .Where and .Select statements

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, func

I'm trying to implement the following as part of a homework assignment for my software design class.

I have the following code:

```
var failureList = evaluators
                       .Where(eval => !eval(ssn)["evaluationPassed"])
                       .Select(eval => eval(ssn)["reason"]);
```

where `evaluators` is an array of `Func<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>` delegate functions that evaluate a certain criteria and return a Dictionary with the result of the evaluation, the `evaluationPassed` key contains a boolean returning whether the candidate passed or failed the evaluation, if this is false, the `reason` key will contain a string further explaining why the evaluation failed, however, if the evaluation passes, the `reason` key will not be present in the result. With multiple evaluations, I am trying to extract the list of reasons for each failing evaluation.

It is mentioned that the evaluation functions could often make expensive database lookups (for example, to check for a candidate's criminal record or credit history) and as such should only be called once, but the way I have implemented it here it is being called twice, once in the where statement that filters only the failing evaluations, and once again in the select statement that grabs the value of the `reason` Key in the resulting dictionary.

Is there a way to essentially cache the result of the eval(ssn) function inside the Where statement to be able to use it in the Select statement? Or maybe a way to tell the Select statement to skip its current iteration if the `reason` key does not exist (thus eliminating the need for a `.Where` statement)? Perhaps there is some syntax that I am not familiar with that could be useful here.

Previously, I have tried to use a ForEach statement to create this list manually, but our professor advised us to switch to these function calls in favor of immutability. However I'm having a hard time figuring out how to avoid the duplicate function call in the Select statement.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do:

```
var failureList = evaluators.Select(eval => eval(ssn))
                            .Where(ssn => !ssn["evaluationPassed"])
                            .Select(ssn => ssn["reason"]);
```

If for some reason you also need to tie that up with `eval`, I would use query syntax:

```
var failureList = from eval in evaluators
                  let ssn = eval(ssn)
                  where !ssn["evaluationPassed"]
                  select new { Eval = eval, Reason = ssn["reason"] };
```

Comment: The first code snippet did the trick, for some reason I hadn't thought about projecting the results of the function first and then filtering before selecting the proper key, very insightful, thank you. I'm still quite new to lambda expressions and functional style programming, but I'm liking it quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try projecting the function call first, then filter on the one key-value pair and projecting the last value:

```
var failureList = evaluators
                   .Select(eval => eval(ssn))
                   .Where(dict => !dict["evaluationPassed"])
                   .Select(dict => dict["reason"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the list of failures first:

```
var failureList = evaluators
                  .Where(eval => !eval(ssn)["evaluationPassed"]).ToList();
```

Then get the reasons:

```
var reasons = failureList.Select(f => f["reason"]).ToList();
```